# I'm facing this error with react-use-gesture

Tags: reactjs, react-use-gesture

sometimes this error gets thrown and it blocks the gestures :

```
315[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs mention this: https://use-gesture.netlify.app/docs/faq/#why-am-i-getting-warnings-from-preventdefault-after-i-pass-passivefalse

The lib does internal checks whether events are cancelable, but there’s no way it could prevent the user from
performing its own logic.

Answer (score 0):

verify if you are using something to prevent some action to happen like:

`event.preventDefault();`

and make some verification first

`if (event.cancelable) event.preventDefault();`

Comment: yes this the solution but its has to be done in the package tho

Comment: @سعيد You should report it to the package developer.  If you need it right away you could try editing the package code.  Maybe if you're successful you can submit it in a pull request (assuming the package is open source)

Comment: @squillman thank you that's what I did I contacted them through their discord and it turns out it was an other dependency that was causing the error